# Spivak - Chapter 10 Problem 19

Tags: calculus

I understand what this question (problem 19) is asking but I'm not sure how to prove it. As you can see below, Spivak says that seeking a formula may be "unwise" and that it may be simpler to prove just the existence of the nth derivative of the composite function. He suggests using induction to do this, but don't you typically induct on a formula? I'm guessing he wants you to induct on the "existence" of the derivative, but I'm not sure how to do this.

[image]

Comment: 1. please do not post pictures of book pages but formatted text. 2. What is the result of your "little experiments"? What is $(f\circ g)^{(1)},(f\circ g)^{(2)},(f\circ g)^{(3)}?$

Answer (score 1):

I guess the point is that a precise formula will be "pretty messy".

Let's see:  $(f\circ g)^{(2)}(a)=(f'(g))\cdot g')'(a)=(f^{(2)}(g)\cdot g'^2+f'(g)g^{(2)})(a)$.

Now it's apparent that $(f\circ g)^{(3)}$ will already involve quite a conglomeration of chain rules and product rules, to where it will be a little difficult to write a formula.

Much easier just to note that we get a sum of terms which are products of powers of $f^{(n)}(g(a))$ and $g^{(n)}(a)$.

But by induction this is what we get:  assume at the $n-1$ stage this is what we get, then apply the product rule and chain rule where applicable, one more time.

Answer (score 1):

Writing the formula for the derivative of the composition of two functions as
$$(f\circ g)'=(f'\circ g)\cdot g'$$
and computing the first few derivatives, you can conjecture that $(f\circ g)^{(n)}$ is a linear combination of terms of the form
$$(f^{(k)}\circ g)\cdot \bigl(g^{(i)}\bigr)^{a_k}\cdot \bigl(g^{(j)}\bigr)^{b_k}$$
where $\quad\begin{array}{|ll}
1\le i, j,k\le n, & a_k,b_k \ge 0,\\[1ex]
ia_k+jb_k=n.
\end{array}$

You can try to prove this assertion by induction.

Comment: "Linear combination" is not a term likely to be known by a student in a first-year calculus course. I might have said "you can conjecture that there are constants $a^n_k, b^n_k, c^n_k$ such that $(f\circ g)^{(n)} = \sum_{1 \le i,j, k \le n } c^n_k (f^{(k)}\circ g)\cdot \bigl(g^{(i)}\bigr)^{a_k}\cdot \bigl(g^{(j)}\bigr)^{b_k}$ and $ia^n_k + jb^n_k = n$ for each triple $i,j,k$."

Comment: Didn't they all study some linear algebra previously?

Comment: I certainly didn't encounter any linear algebra prior to using this book. Spivak was my first calculus book in high school. (I grant this is unusual, but it is explicitly what he intends in the introduction to the text.)

Comment: Here they see some elementary linear algebra as soon as they enter high school.

Comment: @JohnHughes is completely correct. I taught Spivak to college freshmen 15 times or so. Linear algebra came the next year, if at all. Many of my students did not go further in mathematics after a year of Spivak.

Comment: @TedShifrin: ...but those who did go on ... they sure knew a lot more than the folks who learned from Thomas/Finney. :)